# argument of type "int *" is incompatible with parameter of type "int" in cuda kernel call

Tags: cuda

I've been trying for a while and have come across seemingly similar issues already posted however for some reason I'm still failing to clear the error. I'm effectively want to pass a 2D matrix to the kernel as a 1D array as I have seen suggested. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong in my syntax but there is a clash in terms of the variable I supply to the kernel and the parameter that kernel expects.

```
__global__ void calculatePath(int source, int target, int *cost, int distance){

int t_id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;


int dist[50];
int prev[50];
int selected[50]={0};
int num_path[50];

int d, m, min, start, j;

if ((t_id > 0) && (t_id < N)){
    dist[t_id] = IN;
    prev[t_id] = -1;
}
```

This is my kernel function whose parameters are all integers except "cost" which is a pointer to an integer array.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){


int h_num_path[N];
int h_distance = 0;
int h_cost[N][N],i,j,co;
int h_source;
int h_target;

printf("\tShortest Path Algorithm(DIJKSRTRA's ALGORITHM\n\n");
for(i=0;i< N;i++)
    for(j=0;j< N;j++)
        h_cost[i][j] = IN;

//*********************
srand ( time(NULL));
for(int x=1;x< N;x++) {
    for (int y = x + 1; y < N; y++) {
        h_cost[x][y] = h_cost[y][x] = (rand() % 100) + 1;
    }
}

printf("\nEnter The Source: ");
scanf("%d", &h_source);
printf("\nEnter The target: ");
scanf("%d", &h_target);

int *d_num_path;
int *d_cost;
int *d_source;
int *d_target;
int *d_dist;
int *d_prev;
int *d_distance;

cudaMalloc(&d_num_path, sizeof(int)*N);
cudaMalloc(&d_cost, sizeof(int)*N*N);

cudaMalloc((void**) &d_source, sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void**) &d_target, sizeof(int));
cudaMalloc((void**) &d_dist, sizeof(int)*N);
cudaMalloc((void**) &d_distance, sizeof(int));

cudaMemcpy(d_source, &h_source, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_target, &h_target, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_cost, h_cost, sizeof(int)*N*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_distance, &h_distance, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_num_path, &h_num_path, sizeof(int)*N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

clock_t before;
before = clock();

calculatePath<<<N/512 + 1, 512>>>(d_source, d_target, d_cost, d_distance);

clock_t time_taken = clock() - before;

cudaMemcpy(&h_num_path, d_num_path, sizeof(int)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
cudaMemcpy(&h_distance, d_distance, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaFree(d_num_path);
cudaFree(d_cost);
cudaFree(d_source);
cudaFree(d_target);
cudaFree(d_dist);
cudaFree(d_prev);
cudaFree(d_distance);

printf("\nShortest Path: %d \n",co);
printf("%s %.4f %s", "Time taken:", time_taken/1000.0, "seconds");

return 0;
```

}

On the kernel call, I however receive the error that "argument of type 'int *' is incompatible with parameter of type 'int'" yet I believe my d_cost already is a pointer. I'd appreciate being set straight as I'm sure I'm overlooking something small.

Comment: `I'm not sure where I've gone wrong in my syntax `  Read your Error/warning `argument of type “int *” is incompatible with parameter of type “int” ll`

Comment: That is what the error message is telling you: you believe `d_cost` is a pointer, which it is. But the function expects `int`.

Comment: @JpDizzy Do you know whats the difference between an Argument and a parameter?

Comment: What is the function signature of `cudaMalloc()`?

Comment: Doesn't this need a `C` tag?

Comment: @Nguaial thought I had included it. Thanks, updated.

Comment: No it doesn't need the C tag, which is why I removed it. Twice. This is a  CUDA question, and the code isn't C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not `d_target` you are having trouble with. The other three arguments are `int*` but corresponding parameters are declared as `int`.

The C Programming Language by K&R at page 25 says:

> We will generally use *parameter* for a variable named in the parenthesized list in a function definition, and *argument* for the value used in a call of the function.

Since your `source` and `target` are just a single integer values, you don't really need to define device side variables for them. Just pass the integer value itself as an argument. By doing so, you'll get performance improvements as talonmies commented:

> (With pass by value) there is constant memory cache broadcast within the kernel if it is done that way. Passing pointers for simple constants just increases latency by forcing every thread to dereference the pointer to retrieve the value from global memory, plus all the additional host side memory APIs to allocate them in the first place.

Also, you seem to expect parameter `distance` to have output value of your kernel, then it must be declared as a pointer, so you can do `cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost` after kernel.

```
__global__ void calculatePath(int source, int target, int *cost, int *distance) // kernel definition

caculatePath<<< (N + 511) / 512, 512 >>>(h_source, h_target, d_cost, d_distance) // kernel launch
```

Answer (score 0):

Three of your arguments need to be integers, but you are passing pointers to integers.  You need to change your method signature:

```
__global__ void calculatePath(int *source, int *target, int *cost, int *distance)
```

Comment: But you can't dereference those pointers. They are not valid pointers in the host address space

Comment: @talonmies - Initially, these pointers are not pointing to anything (It should be set to NULL in the beginning.). But cudaMalloc() will allocate memory and the values are set using cudaMemcpy().  Why wouldn't dereference work here?

Comment: I knew it was something silly, thanks a lot. I was so focused on the cost variable I didn't pick up on that.

Comment: If the answer helped you please upvote and accept it

Comment: @Nguaial: the values assigned to the pointers are addresses in GPU memory. They are not valid in the host and will cause a segfault if you dereference

Comment: @Nguai - The cudaMalloc allocates them in the GPU memory space, not in the host memory space

Comment: @ChrisRouffer: The thing is, this still isn't a good answer. The *right* answer is to pass by value. Then there is constant memory cache broadcast within the kernel if it is done that way. Passing pointers for simple constants just increases latency by forcing every thread to dereference the pointer to retrieve the value from global memory, plus all the addition host side API memory to allocate them nin the first place

Comment: @talonmies - His question was about a compiler error, not system architecture.  He was hung up on the cost pointer, and missing the fact that the other three parameters were wrong

Comment: @ChrisRouffer: But the underlying reason for all of this is that the OP doesn't understand that CUDA supports pass by value in kernel calls and has mistakenly assumed that all kernel arguments, including constants, need to be allocated memory on the device.